# Having an issue inputting values into DB with PDO

Tags: html, mysql, forms, pdo

So this is the PHP code that processes the form info and it supposed to send data into the DB. It is successful every time and shoots me a success message but when I look in database I see a new row but no actual data from the form.

REMINDER: the db connection is working, except it's sending blank values to fill up the table as opposed to the form data.

Here is the HTML form to be handled by the PHP code in dealer.php:

```
 <form action="dealer.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
   <label for="company">Company Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company Name">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="location">Location</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="founded">Founded</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="founded" name="founded" placeholder="Founded">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="employees"># of Employees</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="employees" name="employees" placeholder="# of employees">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="employees"># of Employees</label>
     <input type="text class="form-control" id="sales" name="sales" placeholder="2014 sales">
  </div>
   <div class="radio">
   <label><p>Is the company traded publicly?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" name="public" id="Yes" value="Yes">
  Yes
 </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" name="public" id="No" value="No">
   No
  </label>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="sr-only" for="gross_2014">Gross Revenue</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gross_2014" name="gross_2014" placeholder="Gross Revenue">
      <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
     </div>
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="sr-only" for="net_2014">Net Revenue</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="net_2014" name="net_2014" placeholder="Net Revenue">
     <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
   </div>
 </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="sr-only" for="growth_2014">Growth(%)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="growth_2014" name="growth_2014" placeholder="Growth %">
      <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
   <div class="form-group">
     <p class="help-block" id="customer" name="customer">Customer profile info...       </p>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
  <div class="form-group">
    <p class="help-block" id="products" name="products">Info about product offerings.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here are the contents of dealer.php that process the HTML form above:

```
<?php
$servername = "XX.XXX.XXX.XX";
$username = "smartkrawl";
$password = "Bondurant15!";
$dbname = "smartkrawl";

class companyInfo{
    public $name;
    public $location;
    public $founded;
    public $employees;
    public $sales;
    public $gross_2014;
    public $net_2014;
    public $growth_2014;

    public function     __construct($name,$location,$founded,$employees,$sales,$gross_2014, $net_2014, $growth_2014) {

    $this->name = $name;
    $this->location = $location;
    $this->founded = $founded;
    $this->employees = $employees;
    $this->sales = $sales;
    $this->gross_2014 = $gross_2014;
    $this->net_2014 = $net_2014;
    $this->growth_2014 = $growth_2014;

    }
}


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,      $password);
     // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO companyInfo (name, location, founded, employees, sales, gross_2014, net_2014, growth_2014)
    VALUES ('$name', '$location', '$founded', '$employees', '$sales', '$gross_2014', '$net_2014', '$growth_2014')";
     // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
   catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;


     ?>
```

Comment: None of your `<input>` elements have a `name` attribute. Without a `name` the data won't be submitted. You're not checking you have any data, so you're submitting empty values to the database.

Comment: Aparat from @HoboSapiens valid comment, you do not seem to be instatiating the companyInfo class and accessing its properties nor POST values.

Comment: See my edit. The same thing is happening.

Comment: and where would I go about doing that in this example?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get the POST values in your php code, that's why the columns of the row are empty. The variables are not set.

I don't think you should use a class just to handle a form, it's unnecessary.

Since you getting this data from a form, it's good to security the use of **prepared statements** to insert the data. You're already using PDO, so you can just use the prepared statements without problem.

You can read about PDO Prepared Statements on PHP Manual (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

I modified your code and now should be working.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['company'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$founded = $_POST['founded'];
$employees = $_POST['employees'];
$sales = $_POST['sales'];
$gross_2014 = $_POST['gross_2014'];
$net_2014 = $_POST['net_2014'];
$growth_2014 = $_POST['growth_2014'];

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO companyInfo (name, location, founded, employees, sales, gross_2014, net_2014, growth_2014) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $sql->bindValue(1, $name);
    $sql->bindValue(2, $location);
    $sql->bindValue(3, $founded);
    $sql->bindValue(4, $employees);
    $sql->bindValue(5, $sales);
    $sql->bindValue(6, $gross_2014);
    $sql->bindValue(7, $net_2014);
    $sql->bindValue(8, $growth_2014);
    $exec = $sql->execute();

    if($exec) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

By the way, in your HTML code, there's a quote missing on this line after the type attribute.

```
<input type="text class="form-control" id="sales" name="sales" placeholder="2014 sales">
```

Replace by

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sales" name="sales" placeholder="2014 sales">
```

And there's a field on the form that you didn't set on your PHP code, which is the `optionsRadios` radio. I didn't put that radio in the code because you didn't put it on the original code. So, if you want to put it there, just add it on the PHP like any other field.